# Pairs on dict (Python)

Tags: python, enumeration

I have a dict with id and randomly generated age. For example (age random):

```
json = {0: {'age': 14},
        1: {'age': 23},
        2: {'age': 43},
        3: {'age': 29}
```

I have a range. For example [5;20]. I want to run through the array like this:

```
0->1, 0->2, 0->3   #FIX
1->2, 1->3
2->3
```

And I want to check if it meets the condition `5 < abs(n-m) < 20`.

1). 0 with 1:

```
if 5 < abs(json[0]['age']-json[1]['age']) < 20:
    pass
```

2). 0 with 2:

```
if 5 < abs(json[0]['age']-json[2]['age']) < 20:
    pass
```

n). n with m:

```
if 5 < abs(json[n]['age']-json[m]['age']) < 20:
    pass
```

So they should all be in the range of each other. In fact, there are several ranges, but I think one is enough for an example. 
I don't really understand how this can be implemented in Python, please help.
Maybe it help:

[image: don't judge the image strictly]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj2Ds.png)

Comment: The numbers are not compatible: where does the 4 come?

Comment: Hello, is the 4 initialized?

Comment: When your 'json' has 4 elements, how would you compare with element at index 4?

Comment: oops, I'll fix it now

Answer (score 0):

An approach of code should look something like this:

```
def checkRange(bottom, top, data):
  lastkey=list(data.keys())[-1]
  for key in data.keys():
    for x in range(key+1, lastkey+1):
      if bottom<abs(data[key]['age']-data[x]['age']) < top:
        pass
      else: 
        print(key, x)

data = {0: {'age': 14},
    1: {'age': 23},
    2: {'age': 43},
    3: {'age': 29}}

checkRange(5,20,data)
```

Instead of printing or passing, you can choose what to do!

Answer (score 0):

I think `itertools.combinations` is crafted for this purpose. You can read the documentation in detail:[itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

In your case, you can call it by:

```
import itertools as it
a=list(it.combinations(json,2))
```

If you print `a`, you can clearly see its the combination of index you want:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)] # print (a)
# what you want
0->1, 0->2, 0->3   #FIX
1->2, 1->3
2->3
```

Then calculate and print the absolute difference between the two items:

```
for item in a:
    print (abs(json[item[0]]['age']-json[item[1]]['age']) )
```

The output is:

```
9
29
15
20
6
14
```

Alternatively, you can shorten the codes and check the range:

```
for i in it.combinations(json,2):
    v=abs(json[i[0]]['age']-json[i[1]]['age'])
    if v in range(5+1,20):
        pass
    else:
        print ('False',i,'age:',v )
```

The output:

```
False (0, 2) age: 29
False (1, 2) age: 20
```

Comment: I just want to show how the combination of index would look like by printing it in a list. Taking your concern, I edited the answer, so that it uses the output directly, without listing it.

Answer (score -2):

This can be done with a one-liner, using whatever range you want to check:

```
range_check = range(5, 21)  # Range second arg is exclusive
# Get answer as a bool value
res = all(abs(json[i]['age'] - json[j]['age']) in range_check
           for i in range(len(json)) for j in range(i-1, -1, -1))
```

Of course this is assuming your `dict` is built as in the example, where the key of each element is its index.

For a more general approach which would work regardless of the keys, you could store the keys as a tuple or a list:

```
range_check = range(5, 21)  # Range second arg is exclusive
keys = tuple(json.keys())
# Get answer as a bool value
res = all(abs(json[key1]['age'] - json[key2]['age']) in range_check
           for i, key1 in enumerate(keys) for key2 in keys[:i])
print(res)
```

Comment: why try to squeeze all that code into one line? makes it unreadable and not easy to understand for beginners. not an ideal answer IMO

Comment: It is subjective of course. I like one liners and think they are more readable  - they are also incredibly powerful in python, which is part of why I like the language. You can do a lot in a very expressive way without much code

Comment: disagree with part of your statement. one-liners are powerful when they are concise and of a moderate length. this one is too long and is _less readable_. your one-liner is so long it doesn't even fit on one line and if it did would violate PEP-8